# Insert,update ,delete,drop sample code by using relation algebra

Tags: apache-calcite

I am new Apache Calcite and am able to fetch the data from DB by using relational algebra ,but not able to do insert,update, delete,drop operation. If can share sample code will be more helpful.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and why it didn't help.

Comment: final FrameworkConfig config = config().build();
    final RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(config);
    final RelNode node = builder.scan("enliven")
      //.distinct()
      //.peek(0);
      //.project(builder.field("Name"),builder.field("event_id"))
      //.project(builder.field("Name"))
      //.limit(0, 1)
      .build();
    PreparedStatement pd = RelRunners.run(node);
    ResultSet resultSet = pd.executeQuery();

Comment: An above one is to get data from calcite,    below one to insert data                                                     
   final RelNode node1 =builder.scan("enliven")
     //.distinct()
     //.peek(0);
     .project(builder.field("Name"),builder.field("event_id"))
     .values(string, values)
     //.project(builder.field("Name"))
     //.limit(0, 1)
     .build();
   
   PreparedStatement pd1 = RelRunners.run(node1);
   pd1.execute();

Comment: Pleae [edit] your question and insert everything there.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware, `RelBuilder` can not build a `RelNode` for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP operations.

For DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE), the equivalent relational algebra uses `TableModify`, so you can call `LogicalTableModify.create` to build one `TableModify` node and use `RelBuilder` to build a RelNode`` as its input as follows:

```
RelNode node = builder.scan("envliven").project("Name");
TableModify modifyNode = LogicalTableModify.create((table,
  schema, node,
  UPDATE, updateColumnList,
  sourceExpressionList, flattened);
```

For DDL (DROP, CREATE, ALTER), there is no corresponding relational algebra，but you can use the `SqlNode` to execute directly like `CalcitePrepareImpl.executeDdl`.

For example:

```
update nation set n_nationkey = 1 where n_nationkey = 2;
```

`RelNode` as follows:

```
LogicalTableModify(table=[[test, nation]], operation=[UPDATE], updateColumnList=[[n_nationkey]], sourceExpressionList=[[1]], flattened=[false]) 
  LogicalProject(n_nationkey=[$0], n_name=[$1], n_regionkey=[$2], n_comment=[$3], EXPR$0=[1]) 
   LogicalFilter(condition=[=($0,2)])
     LogicalTableScan(table=[[test, nation]])
```

For UPDATE, the `updateColumnList` has the column you updated, and the `sourceExpressionList` has the new values.

For INSERT:

```
insert into nation(n_nationkey, n_name) values(1, 'test');
```

`RelNode` as follows:

```
LogicalTableModify(table=[[test, nation]], operation=[INSERT], flattened=[false])
  LogicalProject(n_nationkey=[$0], n_name=[$1], n_regionkey=[null], n_comment=[null])
    LogicalValues(tuples=[[{ 1, _UTF-16'test                     ' }]])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you tell me where we can set the values on given source code which you have shared to insert and update table

Comment: @KamatchiGunasekaran I have add two examples for update and insert.

Comment: @KamatchiGunasekaran if this answer is helpful, you can vote up and accept it.

Comment: Thanks ..let me try